# PHP $_GET is not getting any value

Tags: php

I am trying to make this code works, but I always received a NULL value from
$_GET["page"]

```
<div class="menu">
       
        <ul class="admin-menu">
        
            <?php if (isset($_GET["page"])) : ?>
            
                <?php if ($_GET["page"] == "opt1") : ?>
                    <li class="menu-item">
                       <a class="item-link" href="option1" name="opt1">Altas</a>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                <?php endif ?>

                <?php if ($_GET["page"] == "opt2") : ?>
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a class="item-link" href="baja" name="baja">Bajas</a>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                <?php endif ?>

            <?php endif ?>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <!-- Working area -->
<div class="working">

    <?php
            if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
                
                if (
                    $_GET["page"] == "opt1"   ||
                    $_GET["page"] == "opt2"
                ) {
                    include "admin/admin.".$_GET["page"].".php";              
                }
            } else {
                include "view/pages/system/error404.php";
            }
        ?>

</div>
```

and this is my .htaccess file

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

I really don't know what to do, I saw a lot of examples on line but not luck

thank you for any help

[It suppose to have get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJpva.jpg)

[but i am getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyp9c.jpg)

Comment: Does it work when you enter something like `index.php?page=opt1`?

Comment: You do not seem to have any `<form>` tags. Also, I don't think an `<a>` element works as a form element. You also don't have any elements with the `name` attribute set to `page`. Also, the code in your `<div class="working">` block looks like it has syntax errors. Also, you your HTML is invalid, you never end the first `<div class="menu">` element.

Comment: @Progrock I tried and the answer is NO, it took me to the index.php

Comment: Finally I saw my error,  I used index.php?page=opt1 instead of master.php that is the one who control the system.

Answer (score 2):

you have a syntax error
replace

```
if (
      $_GET["page"] == "opt1"   ||
      $_GET["page"] == "opt2"   ||"
) {
```

with

```
if (
      $_GET["page"] == "opt1"   ||
      $_GET["page"] == "opt2"  
) {
```

Comment: or `if(in_array($_GET["page"], ['opt1', 'opt2']))` ;p

Comment: also it is not clear what you are trying to do with `<a class="item-link active" href="option1" name="opt1">Altas</a>` but is probably not what you want, as the name attribute doesn't serve any purpose in a  `<a>` tag

Comment: Sorry for that, I delete other options i have in the code trying to reduce it, and forgot to delete the OR